# How do I authenticate login credentials using firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a simple login page with a username and password field. I have saved usernames and passwords in firebase-realtime-database. I just want to authenticate it with the input by the user and redirect to another page. I am unable to do this with javascript as I lack the knowledge. How can I do this?
This is my database:
(https://i.ibb.co/1RGLBJs/asasa.png)

I want to write code so that when a person enters his username (eg. 199301111), it goes inside muj-dms/login/199301111 and checks the entered password with the password in the database and this it redirects to another page or shows an error.

```
// code to fetch data from the form
// signup
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#login-form');
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //get user info
    const inp_username = signupForm['username'].value;
    const inp_password = signupForm['password'].value;

    //signup (firebase password doesnt seem to be stored in pass)

    firebase.database().ref('login').child(inp_username).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var pass = snapshot.val().password;
    });
    console.log(inp_password, inp_username);
    console.log(pass);


})
```

UPDATE: So as a comment instructed, I just appended the email and used Firebase Auth. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Welcome! Is there a particular reason you're using RTDB instead of Auth? Do you need to know the passwords? Maybe you shouldn't :) You should authenticate users using Firebase Authentication ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth ). If you need to associate RTDB data with users, use their UIDs.

Comment: @Stratubas Im using it as RTDB allows me to sign in with username whereas Auth requires an email.

Comment: I highly recommend checking out this example on building username+password authentication on Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/username-password-auth

Comment: The email doesn't have to exist. You can use your own usernames and append "@hello.world". But you would lose the automated "forgot password" feature.